# Transformation of Distributions

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

How to reduce Beta distribution of second kind into Beta distribution first kind through transformation?

Comment: Please provide definitions of the first - and second kind Beta distributions. E.g. via hyperlink: `[display](www.google.com)`. – *Reviewer*

Comment: Everything you want to know is given in the Wikipedia entries.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Properties_and_related_distributions